# Is it "come to" vs "come down" to a place?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english, british-english, phrasal-verbs

When asking if they visit the city I live in, What should I say?

> Do you come down to xyz often?

or

> Do you come to xyz often?

Assume xyz is a name of a city.

When instructing someone to come to a place, What should I say?

> Come down to Aqua St

or

> Come to Aqua St.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use any preposition.

We sometimes use *down* to refer to travelling to the southern part of a country. In Britain, it used to be used for travelling away from London. But as a non-native speaker, you don't need to worry about these usages - just say 'to XYZ'.